QGraphicsScene, Center Text on Shape
I'm struggling to center a QGraphicsTextItem on another QGraphicsRectItem. I've set the the SceneRect so I believe that everything should be mapped to [0,0] (as suggested by other posts), but I'm not sure why trying setPos() doesn't align the text element on the rectangle.
Here's the code sample with borders drawn on all the elements:
import sys
from PyQt6.QtCore import *
from PyQt6.QtGui import *
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, parent=None):
        super().__init__(*args, parent=parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Timeline")
        self.resize(1000,500)

        self.toolbar=QToolBar()
        self.toolbar.addAction("New Event")
        self.addToolBar(self.toolbar)

        self.drawScene=QGraphicsScene()
        self.drawView=QGraphicsView()
        self.drawView.setScene(self.drawScene)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.drawView)

        self.drawScene.setSceneRect(0,0,self.window().width(),self.window().height())

        unit_len=200
        winH=self.window().height()
        winW=self.window().width()
        padX=30
        padY=30
        self.drawView.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)

        unitPen=QPen(Qt.GlobalColor.green)
        unitPen.setWidth(0)
        unitBrush=QBrush(Qt.GlobalColor.lightGray)

        units=[2001,2002,2003,2004,2005]
        dist=0
        for i in units:
            r=QRectF(QPointF(padX+dist,(winH/2)-20),QPointF(padX+dist+unit_len,(winH/2)+20))
            self.drawScene.addRect(r,unitPen, unitBrush)

            r=QLineF(QPointF(padX+dist,(winH/2)),QPointF(padX+dist+unit_len,(winH/2)))
            self.drawScene.addLine(r,QPen(Qt.GlobalColor.red))

            t=self.drawScene.addText(str(i))
            t.setPos(QPointF(padX+dist+(unit_len/2), (winH/2)-(t.boundingRect().height()/2)))
            t.setDefaultTextColor(Qt.GlobalColor.blue)
            t.setFont(QFont("Segoe UI",12,700))

            self.drawScene.addRect(t.sceneBoundingRect(),QPen(Qt.GlobalColor.red))
            dist+=unit_len
        self.drawScene.addRect(QRectF(QPointF(padX+dist,(winH/2)-20),QPointF(padX+dist+padX,(winH/2)+20)), QPen(Qt.GlobalColor.white), QBrush(Qt.GlobalColor.white))

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())


As you can see, even though the text should be placed at the center of the unit, it is quite a bit off on both the horizontal and vertical axes.

QGraphicsTextItem uses the QTextDocument interface, so the bounding rect has absolutely nothing to do with the visual representation of the text, but with the size() of the document, eventually based on the metrics of the used font(s), which is not the tight bounding rect of the glyphs (the characters), but based on its standard heights and widths. See the QFontMetrics documentation. If you don't need too many of those items and they're simple enough, consider QGraphicsPathItem.

I see! I've been trying to work out a solution with QPainterPath(), now that I see that it is possible to add text to it. Thank you :)

As musicamante mentioned, QGraphicsPathItem works as a solution to the misalignment.
I replaced the text-drawing part with a path, which aligns to QFontMetrics.tightBoundingRect()'s bounding box. From there, I just averaged the positions and it was centered properly. I think this is more computationally expensive though.
path = QPainterPath()
font=QFont("Segoe UI",12,500)
metrics=QFontMetrics(font)
textRect=metrics.tightBoundingRect(i)
path.addText(QPointF(padX+dist+(unit_len/2)-textRect.width()/2, (winH/2)+textRect.height()/2),font,i)
self.drawScene.addPath(path, QPen(Qt.GlobalColor.black), QBrush(Qt.GlobalColor.black))



The tightBoundingRect() is probably unnecessary. In fact, if you want to center the text within a specific rectangle, you can just work with its boundingRect() and translate it accordingly. Supposing you have a reference QRectF as rect, you can do path.translate(-path.boundingRect().center()) and then addPath(rect.center()).

I forgot to mention an important aspect: by using QPainterPath, you're losing the possibility of relying on subpixel rendering. Right now you're not even using antialiasing (the text shown above is pixelated, while you should normally do self.drawView.setRenderHint(QPainter.RenderHint.Antialiasing)), but even in that case the result won't be exactly the same as drawing actual text: the difference is small, but still noticeable under certain conditions. It may not be that relevant for your needs, but it's still an important aspect to remember.
